# How to get new ip using dhcpcd

Tags: arch-linux, dhcp

I'm using 64-bit ArchLinux and [dhcpcd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dhcpcd#Running). How to retrieve new IP using `dhcpcd`? I've tried to restart the daemon, the IP address i got still the same

```
$ ifconfig
enp3s0: flags ...
   inet xxx ...
$ sudo dhcpcd@enp3s0
$ ifconfig 
enp3s0: flags ...
   inet xxx ... ==> not changed
```

I've tried using `sudo dhclient -v -r` but the IP still the same.

I've found a way, but it still requires clicking on the system tray (disconnect, reconnect):

```
$ sudo rm /var/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-enp3s0.lease
$ sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd@enp3s0
# right click on the network icon on system tray, disconnect, reconnect
```

Comment: You do know that it's possible for the DHCP server to always give the same IP address to a given hardware (MAC, ethernet) address, right? I have my home network's dhcpd configured to give a printer the same IP address every time. No amount of fiddling with dhcpcd will change that, you'd have to change the interface's MAC address.

Comment: I found this answered on server fault: ["How do I force Linux to reacquire a new IP address from the DHCP server?"](https://serverfault.com/questions/42799/how-do-i-force-linux-to-reacquire-a-new-ip-address-from-the-dhcp-server)

Answer (score 5):

You've run `ifconfig` to see the interface name(s), that's a good start. After that, check if the ethernet cable is plugged in and working:

```
[root@splunge ~]# mii-tool enp3s8
enp3s8: negotiated 100baseTx-FD flow-control, link ok
```

That's from a working Arch server. You can use `mii-tool` or `ethtool` to check the connection and cable.

After you are certain the cable is plugged in and working, get rid of any `dhcpcd` still running or hung or something:

```
dhcpcd -k enp3s0
```

Then, run `dhcpcd` with debug messages turned on:

```
dhcpcd -d enp3s0
```

The messages from that invocation may help you decide what to do next.

Note that I'm assuming you will `su -` to log in as root, I find using `sudo` all the time cumbersome. If you want to `sudo`, modify the commands above appropriately.

**EDIT:**

I may have misunderstood your question. If `dhcpcd` is working, then it will always try to get the same IP address it had last time it got a lease.

You can force `dhcpcd` to get a completely different IP address by removing `/var/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-enp3s0.lease`, and then stopping and starting the `dhcpcd` process.